# Spacing out 4 areas in a defined width

Tags: vb.net, graphics, system.drawing, rectangles, aforge

Hey all i am trying to add 4 boxes to an image that's 1280 x 720.

I am wanting to add the boxes to the top of the image but space them out evenly across the 1280 width.

```
Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image)

g.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(90, 255, 255, 255)), New Rectangle(3, 7, 270, 25)) 'The transparent square for Date
g.DrawString(Format(DateTime.Now, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt"), New Font("Arial", 18), Brushes.Black, New PointF(3, 5)) 'The date

g.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(90, 255, 255, 255)), New Rectangle(350, 7, 170, 25)) 'The transparent square for Latitude
g.DrawString("Lat: " & "30.976154", New Font("Arial", 18), Brushes.Black, New PointF(352, 5))

g.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(90, 255, 255, 255)), New Rectangle(670, 7, 180, 25)) 'The transparent square for longitude
g.DrawString("Lng: " & "33.351328", New Font("Arial", 18), Brushes.Black, New PointF(672, 5))

g.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(90, 255, 255, 255)), New Rectangle(970, 7, 120, 25)) 'The transparent square for MPH
g.DrawString("MPH: " & "000", New Font("Arial", 18), Brushes.Black, New PointF(972, 5))

g.Dispose()
```

However i haven't found a sure fire way to making them even across the screen since each rectangle/text is a different width than the ones around it.

Any ideas, thoughts would be great!

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Do you want the boxes all spaced out evenly? Or do you want them to always be proportional to the length of the strings in them? What are you trying to accomplish? A picture might help.

Comment: @user1118321 space them out evenly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply divide the width by the number of labels. Here's some pseudocode:

```
const int NUM_LABELS = 4; 
int divWidth = width / NUM_LABELS;
int i;
for i = 0 to (NUM_LABELS - 1)
    FillRect(i * divWidth, LABEL_HEIGHT, (i + 1) * divWidth, 0); // or whatever you want to do
    MoveTo (i * divWidth, LABEL_HEIGHT);
    DrawString("some string");
```